# screen resolution in opencart

Tags: php, javascript, web, opencart

I am curious to set my styles as per screen resolution in opencart. I am using a simple script which is working on all other php files but it gives a very strange response in open cart, here is the solution which I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var ScreenWidth=screen.width;
var ScreenHeight=screen.height;
var ScreenResolution="<?php $res ?>"=ScreenWidth+"x"+ScreenHeight;
--></script>
```

But when I use res variable for comparing or even in echo, it gives

```
Notice: Undefined variable: res
```

I am stuck with it, any suggestions on it? or any other same solution?

Comment: I'm not even sure what value would possibly replace $res there. You are assigning a value twice in javascript so it would be a variable name I'd expect to see there, not a PHP variable name

Answer (score 1):

Um... Are you trying to define a PHP variable from JavaScript?

It seems you may need to relearn the difference between server-side and client-side code.

However that is a moot point, since you can use CSS3 media queries to make resolution-dependent styles:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    div {background-color: red;}
}
```

That kind of thing. Leave default styles outside of any query, so that browsers that don't support media queries can be styled in the default manner.

Comment: thanks but the biggest draw of css3 is some browsers do not support it. basically i have a div with width in %, so if some one will browse in IE 7,8 on a higher resolution, size will change. That's why I wanted to go with JS, and define different classes for that div according to the resolution size.

Comment: Is there any solution to get the same result that I want, i.e to change just the class/id of a div on different resolution?